# what is exactly is this mule function is about

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I am very new to Dataweave and was playing with function.This might be a very stupid question, but what changes I need to make to get this working?

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun add(a,b) = {
   if (a + b > 10) 1 else 0
} 
---
{
   flag: add(6,2)
}
```

I want the flag to be either 1 or 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the {} in the definition of fun. In this case the curly braces are for creating an object (collection of key:value pairs)

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun add(a,b) = if (a + b > 10) 1 else 0
---
{
   flag: add(6,2)
}
```

Comment: that explained it well. I am trying to learn dataweave 2.0, however, not many resources are out there except the online documentation. Any suggestion as the best way to learn that? is there a good online resource or about the subject? also  what other lang can I learn which gives me a good background in functional programming with lots of online resources?

Answer (score 0):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun add(a,b) = {
   result: if (a + b > 10) 1 else 0
} 
---
{
   flag: add(6,2)
 }
```